# Piping top to text via with crontab and full message?

Tags: cron, top

I am running this:

```
top -b -n 1 -o %MEM > /home/me/top/top.`date +\%F.\%H\%M`.txt
```

Which works fine when I run it, but when I put in crontab for every 10 mins, the `COMMAND` section is always cut off, so rather than the full command I just see `postgres +`.

Can I get the full command from top via crontab?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is setting `COLUMNS` e.g in crontab:

```
COLUMNS=9999 top -b -n 1 -o \%MEM > /home/me/top/top.mem.`date +\%F.\%H\%M`.txt
```